# How deploy dll to GAC in production

Tags: .net, gac, global-assembly-cache

I tested the GAC in dev, I installed it with the gacutil with the Visual studio's CLI.

For production, there is no Visual studio's CLI and no SDK (I think) so my question is

How can I deploy the dll's to GAC without gacutil? Is it possible to make a sort of exe or msi to put all dll's to server and developper's comuter?

Many thanks to help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some official information by Microsoft:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It seems that you have 2 solutions: Using an installer or using GacUtil. Since GacUtil is not installed (it comes with an SDK), you should go for the installer option.

Comment: ok thanks. I have lots of applications that use same dll's so I have to use the installer option, I have to make that manipulation in every projects? It is a simple webservice, not a desktop application!

Comment: Once a dll is in the GAC, it's not needed to be added again. If your application are dependent upon eachother, it should be sufficient to install just the first one. All the other can use the dll from the GAC which has been installed with the first project.

Comment: OK, so Can I make a separate project that just install DLL's in GAC on production ?

Comment: Well, I cannot test this, but I think this should work. Items which are in GAC will be automatticly used by projects depending on this. Note that you will need to sign your assembly with a strong name.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm in the Files Application Data, and I add the GAC on the "Destination Computer's folder", but I don't know how to add signed dll's to the GAC, Can I select them fom the source's folders?

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but my knowledge of making installers is very limited. I suggest you look around at the documentation to get you started.

Comment: drag n drop with the right click from dll's to GAC apparently, I'm testig it :-)

Answer (score 0):

USing Installshield prepare the deployment package and that will help in installing the assemblies.

Comment: Thanks. This application is a webservice, not a desktop application so We install/unisnatt/start/stop it with CLI,... I don't think Installshield will help us... isn't it?

Comment: I've been using installshield to deploy webapp here is the link [link] http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield17helplib/HelpLib.htm#IISVirtualRoots_WebSvcSupport.htm